# Error SMTP Error: data not accepted in PHPMailer

Tags: php, pdf, phpmailer, html-email, email-attachments

I have been using PHPMailer for around 2 months in my website to send an email to my users with some information about technology and something like that. This email is sent when the user go to the website and click on the "Get my Month Newspaper" button. The content of the email is just some text on the body and a pdf file with the information. All was working very fine, the emails was sent without troubles, but today a user has sent me an email telling me that he didn't receive his email when he did click on the button. when I checked the php mailsender file I got this error message:

```
 SMTP Error: data not accepted.
```

I used $mail->SMTPDebug = true to get more details of the errors and I this is part of the message I got:

```
//this is the first part of the message:

2019-06-30 02:29:11 SMTP INBOUND: "235 2.7.0 Authentication successful"
2019-06-30 02:29:11 SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
2019-06-30 02:29:11 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<here is the same email of SMTP username>
2019-06-30 02:29:11 SMTP INBOUND: "250 2.1.0 Sender OK"
2019-06-30 02:29:11 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.0 Sender OK
2019-06-30 02:29:11 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<here the email of the user>
2019-06-30 02:29:11 SMTP INBOUND: "250 2.1.5 Recipient OK"
2019-06-30 02:29:11 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.5 Recipient OK
2019-06-30 02:29:11 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
2019-06-30 02:29:10 Connection: opening to smtp.office365.com:587, timeout=20, options=array()
2019-06-30 02:29:10 Connection: opened

//this is the part where show the error:
2019-06-30 02:29:12 SMTP INBOUND: "554 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:InvalidLicenseException; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message Mailbox 'here the mailbox code' doesn't have a valid license. InvalidLicenseException: Mailbox 'here the mailbox code' doesn't have a valid license. [Hostname=here the host code]"
SMTP Error: data not accepted.
SMTP Error: data not accepted.
2019-06-30 02:29:12 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2019-06-30 02:29:12 SMTP INBOUND: "221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel"
2019-06-30 02:29:12 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel
2019-06-30 02:29:12 Connection: closed
```

This is my emailsender.php file where the code to send email is:

```
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
                use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

                /* Exception class. */
                require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php'; //PHPMailer

                /* The main PHPMailer class. */
                require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';

                /* SMTP class, needed if you want to use SMTP. */
                require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

                $mail = new PHPMailer(TRUE);
                $mail->isSMTP();

                $mail->Host= 'smtp.office365.com';     // (SMTP)
                $mail->SMTPAuth= 'true';
                $mail->Username= 'username email for SMTP'; 
                $mail->Password= 'here the password of SMTP';   
                $mail->SMTPSecure= 'tls';   
                $mail->Port= '587';   
                $mail->SMTPDebug = true;
                $mail->Timeout = 20;

                $emailUsers = trim("usermail@mailserver.com", " ");
                $message = "";

               try {
               /* Set the mail sender. */
               $mail->setFrom("here the same email of USERNAME SMTP", "Admin"); 
               $mail->addAddress($emailUsers); 

               /* Set the subject. */
               $mail->Subject = 'Month Newspaper';

               $mail->isHTML(TRUE);

               /* Set the mail message body. */
               $message = '<html>'.
                                '<head><title>Nivagastro Order Details</title></head>'.
                                '<body><h4 style="color: blue;"> Welcome to your Month Newspaper. UserAddress:  '.utf8_decode('here the address of the user').' UserAuthWord: '.utf8_decode('This is the auth word of user').'!</h4>'.
                                '<hr style="margin-right: 100px;">'.
                                '<span>We will have new surprises for you the next month. More topics and news. Back soon!</span>'.
                                '</body>'.
                                '</html>';

               $mail->Body = $message;
               $mail->MsgHTML = $message;
               $mail->AltBody = $message;

               $mail->AddAttachment("files/NewspaperJun19.pdf"); // attachment
                if(!$mail->send()) 
                {
                    //echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    echo "YOUR EMAIL HAS BEEN SEND SUCCESSFULY";
                }

                }
                catch (Exception $e)
                {
                   /* PHPMailer exception. */
                   echo $e->errorMessage();
                }
                catch (\Exception $e)
                {
                   /* PHP exception (note the backslash to select the global namespace Exception class). */
                   echo $e->getMessage();
                }
```

Do you have any idea of why does this error is shown now when this was working well till yesterday? and How I can solve this?

Comment: That sounds like there is an issue of that user's mail box, not of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the SMTP Debug Log:

```
2019-06-30 02:29:12 SMTP INBOUND: "554 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:InvalidLicenseException; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message Mailbox 'here the mailbox code' doesn't have a valid license. InvalidLicenseException: Mailbox 'here the mailbox code' doesn't have a valid license. [Hostname=here the host code]"
```

The *inbound* message *"InvalidLicenseException: Mailbox 'here the mailbox code' doesn't have a valid license. [Hostname=here the host code]"* points towards the primary problem being the user's mail box, it seems not to have the required license.

Did the user in question send you the email using the same sender address as he used to register on your site? In that case answering that email might be an interesting test - does it get through to the user or not...

Comment: the user wrote me from his own email account, but he did not write from a form on my website, he did it in a conventional way. He is not the only user with that problem.

Comment: I have several web pages where I also use phpmailer and these smtp credentials for sending contact forms and things like that. 
but I have not checked if those pages present the same error.

Comment: Just to clarify, I assumed that by 'here the mailbox code' and by 'here the host code' you meant the data from the user address. Is that correct or was there actually your own sender address?